# Loading Genymotion library Genymotion directory: /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS Trying to initialize engine Initialize Engine: failed

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, genymotion

the problem is same as topic

```
Loading Genymotion library
Genymotion directory: /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS
Trying to initialize engine
Initialize Engine: failed
```

I have installed virtualbox 5.0.0 and successfully executed.
If I directly run the genymotion app, it also works.
However, I clicked the icon pluged in eclipse then it appears the error message.
I've searched the solution on the website. And then, I've relocated the directory of genymotion.app but it still didn't work. 
Are there any people have the same experience likes mine?
I'll thank you if you guys have some method.

Comment: what is your Genymotion version?

Answer (score 4):

Though I don't using Eclipse, I think I can answer your question.  Since I experienced same issue with Android Studio.

This might be compatibility issue between Genymotion plugin and VirtualBox.

In Genymotion FAQ, they mentions that compatible VirtualBox version is 4.3.12.  ( See [What are the VirtualBox versions compatible with Genymotion?](https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/support?chapter=compatible-virtualbox-versions#faq) )

In my environment, Genymotion itself version 2.5.2 and it's plugin version 1.0.3, the highest VirtualBox version which can work with Genymotion plugin was 4.3.28.

So, unfortunately, even though virtual device can be executed from Genymotion.app with VirtualBox 5.0, Genymotion plugin seems can not be work with VirtualBox 4.3.30 and later...

Comment: If you agree with my answer, you can post support request to Genymotion.  The URL is [Here](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support#contact)

Comment: I can confirm this after emailing Genymotion.
Damien from the Genymotion support team confirmed that Genymotion plugins don't work with VirtualBox 5.0
There is no release that currently works with VirtualBox 5.0 yet.

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by a bug that does not let Genymotion plugin work with VirtualBox later than 4.2

To fix this error all you need to do is go here:
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_2
and download the 4.2 version of VirtualBox. Once you reinstall it - the error is gone and Genymotion plugin opens device list properly

Answer (score 1):

Today I had same issue, but solved.

Please try this way.

1. Run the genymotion virtual device.

2. Eclipse, Click  "Run Configurations".

3. In the "Target" tab, enable the "Always prompt to pic  device".

4. Click "Run"  button.

5. Showing genymotin device. choose that and click "OK" button.

[image: select genymotion device]

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue.

VirtualBox 4.3.12 (the recommended version) is consistently causing a Kernel Panic when attempting to Simulate in OSX Yosemite.

Upgrading to 4.3.30 (the maintained 4.3 release), fixed Genymotion / VirtualBox causing Kernel Panics, but introduced the issue you described above.

As I knew the Genymotion instance was working (even if 4.3.30 is not officially supported), it was just an issue with the Genymotion Plugin and not Android Studio / Eclipse.

This link was the final key to fixing!

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/genymotion-users/MnrANs_FMBs

Here's the line:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage /usr/bin/VBoxManage
```